# Bulma css framework columns not stacking on Chrome mobile browser

Tags: html, css, responsive, bulma

I'm trying to figure out why my small static webpage isn't showing up properly when viewed on mobile (noticed on Chrome android app). According to the docs, the columns should automatically stack on mobile. But, when I view it I see a normal view of the page with the width fitting correctly to the screen, but the columns stay in one row. Shown in the below screenshot.
[image: Incorrect mobile rendering on Chrome android app]

I tested to see if it's my code by resizing the page on a desktop browser and the page responded as expected, stacking the cards so in a single column. Here's a desktop-view imitated on my phone.
[image: Correct mobile rendering outside of Chrome android app]

Any idea what's going on? What am I doing wrong? Here's the code

```
<html>
<head>

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bulma/0.4.3/css/bulma.css"/>

</head>
<body style="background-color:#00aced;">

    <div class="container">
        <div class="notification" style="background-color:#fff">
            <strong>Remember:</strong> In order to continually receive updates, please install the GoodSamarit4n repository from 
            <a href="">here</a>. This is the <em>only</em> official source. The reason I am providing links to the add-on zips is for complete transparency and for those who would like to study and learn from the code.
            <br>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div style="padding: 20px;" class="container">

        <div class="columns">
            <div class="column">
                <div class="card">
                    <div class="card-image">
                        <figure class="image is-4by3">
                            <img src="https://pugdaddy.000webhostapp.com/images/githubforkodi.png" alt="Image">
                        </figure>
                    </div>
                    <header class="card-header">
                        <p class="card-header-title">
                            Githubforkodi
                        </p>
                    </header>
                    <div class="card-content">
                        <div class="content">
                            A kodi program add-on for managing your github account. View repos, branches, notifications, Open/Close/Comment on issues, Merge/Deny pull requests, Get real-time notifications, And much more! The power of github combined with the simplicity of kodi.
                            Creator <a href="https://twitter.com/good_samarit4n">@goodsamarit4n</a>. <a>#kodi</a> <a>#github</a> <a>#program</a> <a>#add-on</a>
                            <br>
                            <small>8:00 PM - 24 Jul 2017</small>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="column">
                <div class="card">
                    <div class="card-image">
                        <figure class="image is-4by3">
                            <img src="https://pugdaddy.000webhostapp.com/images/pugdonut.png" alt="Image">
                        </figure>
                    </div>
                    <header class="card-header">
                        <p class="card-header-title">
                            Squeee!
                        </p>
                    </header>
                    <div class="card-content">
                        <div class="content">
                            A kodi video add-on that provides cute, funny, and heartwarming animal videos from all over the internet. Skip the endless clicking around your favorite sites and let Squeee! bring all of those sites to you in an easy-to-digest fashion. Click through videos one at a time or play an entire playlist and just sit back and embrace the fluffy.
                            Creator <a href="https://twitter.com/good_samarit4n">@goodsamarit4n</a>. <a>#kodi</a> <a>#squeee</a> <a>#video</a> <a>#add-on</a> <a>#cute</a> <a>#animals</a>
                            <br>
                            <small>8:00 PM - 24 Jul 2017</small>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="column">
                <div class="card">
                    <div class="card-image">
                        <figure class="image is-4by3">
                            <img src="https://pugdaddy.000webhostapp.com/images/illuminati.jpg" alt="Image">
                        </figure>
                    </div>
                    <header class="card-header">
                        <p class="card-header-title">
                            Alternative Facts
                        </p>
                    </header>
                    <div class="card-content">      
                        <div class="content">
                            Get ready to get beligerantly angry or find yourself continually muttering "What the f###?" under your breath. For those who enjoy seeing just how crazy some folks are. With documentaries on conspiracy theories gathered from all over the web. If you don't see a topic, feel free to tweet at me and I'll see about adding it for you.
                            Creator <a href="https://twitter.com/good_samarit4n">@goodsamarit4n</a>. <a>#kodi</a> <a>#alternativefacts</a> <a>#video</a> <a>#add-on</a> <a>#conspiracy</a> <a>#theories</a>
                            <br>
                            <small>8:00 PM - 24 Jul 2017</small>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Adding the following meta tag may solves the problem.

```
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
</head>
```

Comment: Oh man, I can't believe it was that simple. However, I couldn't seem to find where it said that in the docs (or at least not where they discuss the columns class). Thank you so much!

Comment: It's been standard rule for controlling layout for mobile devices and I also learnt it from [bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/getting-started/#template) world! You can read more about it [here](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_rwd_viewport.asp) and [there](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Mozilla/Mobile/Viewport_meta_tag). @CaffeinatedCoder

Comment: Thanks for providing some background. I had no idea since this is my first time trying to make a site work on mobile :P

Comment: I'm giving a star to this answer just because it solved my problem with stacking elements of a Level on mobile